# How to Output value from function to caller but not to console

Tags: function, powershell

Say I have this simple PowerShell function:

```
function testit() {
    return $true > $null
}

Write-Host "testing"
$thistest = testit 
Write-Host "value = $thistest"
```

When I use it in my PowerShell script, I want to receive the value in the script but I don't want it to show in the console.

How do I keep the return value in the pipeline but just hide it from console?

If I use the `> $null` then it suppresses the output completely - I just want it to not show in the console, but I still want the value.

Comment: What is wrong with `return $true` or just `$true`?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking; it doesn't show in the console normally. `function test { $true }; $x = test` has no on-screen output, and it keeps the return value in `$x`

Comment: it does if you call the function.  What I don't want is `return $true` to show `True` in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return) PowerShell functions return all non-captured output to the caller. If the caller doesn't do anything with the returned value PowerShell automatically passes it to [`Out-Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default), which then forwards it to [`Out-Host`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host) (see [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg213852.aspx) written by Don Jones).

Using redirection operators on the return value inside the function effectively suppresses the return value so that the function wouldn't return anything.

If you have a function like this:

```
function testit {
    return $true
}
```

and call it by itself:

```
testit
```

PowerShell implicitly does this:

```
testit | Out-Default
```

which effectively becomes

```
testit | Out-Host
```

If you capture the return value in a variable

```
$thistest = testit
```

the value gets stored in the variable without anything being displayed on the console.

If you redirect the output or pipe it into `Out-Null`

```
testit >$null
testit | Out-Null
```

the return value is discarded and nothing is displayed on the console.

If you want to prevent PowerShell's default behavior of passing uncaptured output at the end of a pipeline to `Out-Host` you can do so by overriding `Out-Default` like this:

```
filter Out-Default { $_ | Out-Null }
```

or (as @PetSerAl pointed out in the comments) like this:

```
filter Out-Default {}
```

However, beware that this modification disables `Out-Default` for everything in the current scope until you remove the filter again. If you do for instance a `Get-ChildItem` while the filter is active nothing will be displayed unless you explicitly write the output to the host console:

```
Get-ChildItem | Out-Host
```

You remove the filter like this:

```
Remove-Item function:Out-Default
```

Comment: What a wonderful answer!  Just what I needed and wanted.  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you pipe `$_` to `Out-Null` instead of doing nothing (`function Out-Default { }`)?

Comment: @PetSerAl Because I failed to realize that would work too. Thanks for pointing it out, I updated my answer.

Comment: So, there's no way to make it return a value to the caller, but not to the console except by calling it from another function?