# How do I find out from within a cmdlet the alias the cmdlet was called with?

Tags: powershell

Do you know of a way to find out from within a cmdlet, the alias that cmdlet was called with? I have tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
Function Write-Verbose {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($val)
    $CommandName = $Test.MyInvocation.line -replace '(^.+? ).*','$1'
    Write-host "$val Called with '$CommandName' alias"

}
Set-Alias WB Write-Verbose -Scope global
WB "goodbye"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this from `$MyInvocation.InvocatioName`:

```
Function Write-Verbose {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param($val)

    Write-host "$val Called with $($MyInvocation.InvocationName) alias"    
}
Set-Alias WB Write-Verbose -Scope global
WB "goodbye"
```

Returns:

> goodbye Called with WB alias

Comment: Great problem/post, but overriding `Write-Verbose` seems ill-advised

Comment: This question came from a friend and we're having that debate now actually. His use case is to monkey patch write-* to output ANSI colour code so jenkins coloured output works.

Comment: Wouldn't [filtering output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476196/1630171) be a better approach?

Comment: What's the advantage of filtering? It doesn't seem to preserve the original behaviour of things like Write-Error. I'm thinking of following what's outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747257/can-i-override-a-powershell-native-cmdlet-but-call-it-from-my-override

Comment: The advantage of an `Out-Default` filter is that it affects only (host/console) output, not further pipeline processing.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true as the following code:
`
Filter Write-Error { Write-Host $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments[0]}
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Try{
    Write-Error "Hello"
}catch{
    Write-Host "Caught"
}
`
returns "Hello" instead of Caught?

Comment: @SamMartin There is no pipeline in the code you posted. Besides, if you want to raise an error use `throw`, not `Write-Error`. It's the correct semantic and actually does what you would expect.