# Suppress Array List Add method pipeline output

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am using an Array List to build a sequence of log items to later log. Works a treat, but the Add method emits the current index to the pipeline. I can address this by sending it to $null, like this

```
$strings.Add('junk') > $null
```

but I wonder if there is some mechanism to globally change the behavior of the Add method. Right now I have literally hundreds of `> $null` repetitions, which is just ugly. Especially when I forget one.

I really would like to see some sort of global variable that suppresses all automatic pipelining. When writing a large script I want to intentionally send to the pipeline, as unexpected automatic send to pipeline is a VERY large fraction of my total bugs, and the hardest to find.

Comment: You can suppress the output from appearing in the console ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476196/1630171)), but it would still be captured or returned by functions. AFAIK there's no general option that would suppress the output of the `Add()` method. Why are you using an `ArrayList` collection in the first place? Do you need a particular feature that regular PowerShell arrays don't provide?

Comment: @Ansgar, yes, I am constantly adding an arbitrary number of new log line items, and += is not very efficient in that situation. Ending every Add with > $null isn't the end of the world, so I'll keep doing that. And keep dreaming of a global pipeline suppression option for scripting, so I can choose what goes to the pipeline, rather than needing to suppress a ton of stuff I don't want in the pipeline.

Comment: I am curious, when would anyone actually need to get the element count at every add, vs just discretely getting the Count? I don't understand the use case for this "feature", which is part of why it annoys me so. :)

Comment: Curious why nobody recommended to use `Collections.Generic.List<T>` as answer to this question... it's been there since .NET 2.0 iirc

Comment: Hadn't looked at this thread in ages, but in the end that is EXACTLY what I did.

Comment: Hahha well you should self-answer and give your question closure no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, this thread getting resurrected has led me to "answer" my own question, since I discovered long ago that `ArrayList`s have been deprecated and `Collections.Generic.List<T>` is the preferred solution, as pointed out by @santiago-squarzon today.

So, for anyone wondering

```
$log = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()
```

or the older New-Object way

```
$log = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
```

to instantiate the collection, then happily

```
$log.Add('Message')
```

with no pipeline pollution to worry about. You can also add multiple items at once with

```
$log.AddRange()
```

With the range being another list, or an array if you cast to List first.
And you can insert a message with something like

```
$log.Insert(0, 'Message')
```

So yeah, lots of flexibility and no pollution. Winning.

Comment: However this adds pollution for `.Remove()`, `[System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]` outputs "True" if successfully removed. While `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` outputs the index only for `.Add()`. So it's a stalemate, and we still haven't found a solution that works for all operations.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap your `ArrayList` in a custom object with a custom `Add()` method.

```
$log = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    Log = New-Object Collections.ArrayList
}
$log | Add-Member -Type ScriptMethod -Name Add -Value {
    Param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
      [string]$Message
    )

    $this.Log.Add($Message) | Out-Null
}

$log.Log.Add('some message')  # output on this is suppressed
```

Comment: out-null works but the overhead of pipes could be significant in large loops

Comment: Pipes became the bane of my existence towards the end of my PowerShell based life. I wanted nothing more than to have a flag that just turned them off, since they got polluted all the time, and massive performance problems, and are a real PITA to debug. Instead I dumped PowerShell, sold my old product and my new venture will be 100% Swift. I won't miss PowerShell.